# I am facing this problem in R, AOV function

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
> av = aov(r ~ tf);av
```

r = matrix with numerical data
tf= factor data
This is the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = r ~ tf, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'tf')
```

What is possibly wrong? I am very new to this, I have checked my previous steps and everything seems right. Please let me know if you need any additional information

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows of the matrix should be the same as the `length` of the `vector` 'tf'. If that is not the case, it would show the `length` difference error.  Below code works as the number of rows of 'r' is 10 and length of 'tf' is 10

```
r <- matrix(rnorm(5 * 10), 10, 5)
tf <- factor(sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE))
aov(r ~ tf)
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked, My data was in wrong format.